# How to GET a page that requires Github authorization?

Tags: curl, web-scraping, github-api

I want to GET a page that requires authorization via Github. I can browse that page with my web browser, but I want to parse it in a command shell to scrape some data (the website doesn't have a web API, unfortunately).

I'm using `curl` command line utility. I have my Github login/password in `.netrc`. I'm doing:

```
curl -n https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

to get the list of all available authorizations, and the authorization on the website I want to GET is present there.

Am I using the right approach? What do I do next with that data to authorize on a page I want to scrape?

Comment: What is the URL for the page you are trying to scrape? (Note that you cannot use your GitHub **API** credentials to make an authenticated request to https:/github.com.)

Comment: @jasonrudolph It is http://www.netbout.com/ When you're authenticated, it shows your personal info.